# Azure AppGW in front of APIM without vnet

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I'm in process of setting up an Azure APIM architecture.
One of the requirements is to be able to handle both internal and external api's.

To do so there is a nice architecture (and lots of documentation) where APIM is in a VNET and an APPGW is in front to route or block external/internal traffic to APIM :

[image]

However this setup is only possible with premium APIM, aka the rather expensive edition.
For cost optimisation we would prefer to use the Standard edition if possible.

So my question : is it possible to implement the above architecture (APPGW in front of APIM) where APIM is not in a vnet.  This to meet requirements to secure APIM and to expose internal/external api's.

I would think it is possible, the APPGW would have the public APIM ip in its backendpool to make the connection.  however now that connection goes over the internet, which is insecure or will azure do some internal network routing for this ?

or more general : what's a best practice architecture when APIM is not VNET integrated ?

Could not find any detailed documentation that covers this topic.

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only benefit you would get of putting a public apim behind application gateway is the layer 7 load balancing (which you may not need), but you will not benefit from any of the security features of the application gateway. On the apim side, you may block any traffic that does not come from the traffic manager public ip using the [ip-filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs) policy but the request still be arriving to your apim service and be blocked there instead of being blocked on the application gateway side which can be integrated with WAF to add extra security layer. So, the idea here is that your APIM service is still publicly accessible from anywhere in the world!

Comment: so if I understand correctly: 
 > it is possible to put APPGW in front of APIM( outside vnet), however the connection between APPGW and APIM is via the public APIM endpoint over the internet.  
 > To secure this, IP whitelisting in APIM is necessary to only admit connections from APPGW towards APIM.

that's correct ?

Comment: The apim service is still publicly accessible, no matter if the connection between the app gateway and the apim goes through the internet or Microsoft network as the apim itself is still accessible from any device in the world connected to the internet so no magic is being done by azure to restrict the access only to the app gateway. Yes, you need the ip-filter policy but that does not mean that your apim public  ip is hidden, it is still accessible to anyone but the core apim component (gateway) that processes the client requests will reject any requests that is denied by the ip-filter policy

Comment: APIM has other components as well, not just the gateway, you have the Management Component which helps managing the entities, the developer portal component as well that helps your customers to try and subscribe to products and apis and some other components, so with the above setup, you are only managing the access to the gateway components, but the other ones are still exposed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the frontend setup is clear for me now.
what about the backend services; let's say APIM is outside the vnet and APIM needs to route to an azure service (function, appservice,sqldb,..) inside the vnet, any thoughts/restrictions here?

Comment: as long as the apim is not in the same vnet of those resources, they should expose public ip that apim can connect to, otherwise, it would not be possible. Every service has its own way to restrict incoming calls, so you have to look up every service's documentation to figure that out

Comment: just to correct, "same vnet or peered vnet/network"

Answer (score 0):

You could have some [network restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) but your APIM would still be exposed over the internet and azure will not take extra mesure to protect the traffic between your App Gateway, APIM and backends.

Some services can route their traffic through [Microsoft Global Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/routing-preference-overview#routing-via-microsoft-global-network) but unfortunately APIM is not one of them.

Please make sure you are using HTTPS between you services and set some whitelisting in place.